# Tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to retrieve the average RGB value in an image

```
def DetectColour((x ,y) ,n, image):
    r, g, b = 0, 0, 0
    count = 0
       for s in range(x, x+n+1):
           for t in range(y, y+n+1):
               pixlr, pixlg, pixlb = image[s, t]
               r += pixlr
               g += pixlg
               b += pixlb
               count += 1
    return((r/count), (g/count), (b/count))
```

I figure that something in this code is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it

The error in question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Sound-o-Colour.py", line 74, in <module>
    r, g, b = DetectColour((25, 25) ,5 ,image) #finds the average colour in the frame
  File "C:\Python27\Sound-o-Colour.py", line 19, in DetectColour
    pixlr, pixlg, pixlb = image[s, t] #Counts the pixels of each colour, red, green and blue
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: `image` appears to be a tuple, rather than whatever you expected it to be. Check how this function is called.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the index `[s, t]` to represent?

Comment: The message tells you that the problem occurs on line 19. Which line of code is this and what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access a member of a list or tuple, which I suppose image is you do it with an integer inside sqare brackets like so :

```
image[0]
```

I think you are maybe trying to do this:

```
image[s][t]
```

This would access the int(s) member of `image` list/tuple.
If this member happens to be a list also, you can access it's memebers by adding another square bracket with an inte inside it specifying the index of this member. 
If your loop is taking you through matrix of pixels in an image this makes sense also since with the first loop you might be going through rows of pixels and with the second through columns and try to retreive the RGB values.